# How to make a carousel with a floating item

Tags: javascript, frontend, carousel

I'm trying to find a library to make this kind of slide for my website
[image]

And i've tried searching but still haven't found a solution to my problem, hope someone has done it before can give me ideas or a small demo, thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 1):

I found two libraries similar to what you're trying to do. consider that you should customize css and animations to match your design.

[flip-element-carousel](https://www.cssscript.com/flip-element-carousel/)

[3d-carousel](https://www.cssscript.com/3d-carousel/)